# Changing or adding space variables in Chakra-ui custom theme

Tags: typescript, next.js, themes, token, chakra-ui

How to add / change space variables in a custom theme in Chakra UI?

In my following approach all other extensions are working as expected. Spacing changes are ignored completely.

```
const config: ThemeConfig = {
  initialColorMode: 'light',
  useSystemColorMode: false,
}
const myNewTheme = {
  styles: {
    global: {
      body: {
        bg: 'bgLight',
      },
    },
  },
  colors,
  fonts: {
    body: 'Bitter, serif',
    heading: 'Poppins, sans-serif',
  },
  fontSizes: {
    vw1: 'calc(max(16vw, 2rem))',
  },

  space: {
    spacing: {
      96: '28rem',
     112: '32rem'
    },
  },
  breakpoints,
  components: {
    Button,
    Heading,
  },
}

const fsiTheme = extendTheme(myNewTheme, { config })

export default fsiTheme
```

And I tried

```
 spacing: {
    space: {
      96: '28rem',
      112:'32rem'
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys from Chakra kindly helped me out. If someone else might stumble into this. The solution is to extend the theme with just space.

```
const myNewTheme = {
  space: {
      96: '28rem',
     112: '32rem'
    },
}
```

const fsiTheme = extendTheme(myNewTheme)

export default fsiTheme